# Java: How to check correct login wit LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I try to authenticate against an ActiveDirectory by LDAP and search some objects.
All is fine if correct username (SECURITY_PRINCIPAL) and password (SECURITY_CREDENTIALS) is provided.

InitialDirContext fails if wrong user or password. But if fails NOT if password is an empty string. Then the search fails (no binding).

Any way I can check if authentication is correct directly after InitialDirContext even with password is empty???

```
        Hashtable <String, Object> env = new Hashtable <String, Object> ();         
        env.put (javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put (javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://my.sys.abc:636");
        env.put (javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put (javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=myuser,OU=My,OU=Dev,DC=xyz,DC=abc");  
        env.put (javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mysecret");
        env.put (javax.naming.Context.REFERRAL, "follow");

        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext (env);
        // throws exception if wrong password
        // does not throw if password is ""

        // being here: password was correct OR ""   

        SearchControls cons = new SearchControls ();
        cons.setSearchScope (SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            
        NamingEnumeration <SearchResult> ne = ctx.search (....
        // throws exception if password was ""
```

Comment: By design, LDAP protocol automatically switch the authentication from "simple" to "none" if a password is not supplied ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/simple.html)), resulting in an unauthenticated (but successful) binding, hence no error at this moment but only after when doing an operation that requires to be authenticated. I guess it's fine to make the code throw an AuthenticationException if the password string is empty, just as InitialDirContext does when a wrong password is supplied, so that you can catch both seamlessly.

Comment: Can you make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, LDAP protocol automatically switches the authentication from "simple" to "none" if a password is not supplied (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/simple.html)), resulting in an unauthenticated (but successful) binding, hence no error at this moment but only after when doing an operation that requires to be authenticated.

So I guess it's fine to make the code throw an `AuthenticationException` if the password string is empty, just as `InitialDirContext` does when a wrong password is supplied, so that you can catch both seamlessly.